# gym car racing v0 using DQN

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, jupyter, dqn, openai-gym

I am currently learning reinforcement learning and wanted to use it on the car racing-v0 environment. I have successfully made it using PPO algorithm and now I want to use a DQN algorithm but when I want to train the model it gives me this error:

> AssertionError: The algorithm only supports (<class 'gym.spaces.discrete.Discrete'>,) as action spaces but Box([-1. 0. 0.], [1. 1. 1.], (3,), float32) was provided

Here is my code:

```
import os
import gym
from stable_baselines3 import DQN
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy

environment_name = 'CarRacing-v0'
env = gym.make(environment_name)

#Test Environment
episodes = 5
for episode in range(1, episodes+1):
    obs = env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0
    
    while not done:
        env.render()
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        score += reward
    print('Episode:{} Score:{}'.format(episode, score))
env.close()

env = gym.make(environment_name)
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])

log_path = os.path.join('Training', 'Logs')
model = DQN('CnnPolicy', env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log = log_path)
```

I am using jupyter notebook for this project

Answer (score 0):

Is says model works with discrete envs only, try add `continuous=False` when you create env.

More info
https://www.gymlibrary.dev/environments/box2d/car_racing/
https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/algos.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/82276)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).